# Batch file to move files works perfectly for English named files, but fails for non English file names

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, move, hebrew

I have a flawlessly working batch file when dealing with filenames using common English alphabet characters, but it fails miserably for some using non English ones.

Batch file:

```
Rem Command to move all files that have "2013" in the file name to a specified directory.

for /F "eol=: delims=" %F in ('dir /b|find "2013"') do (
 move /Y "%F" "M:\Hebrew\_Movies - Hebrew 2011-2015" )
```

Output:

```
M:\Hebrew Unsorted>move /Y "2013 ??? ???" "M:\Hebrew\_Movies - Hebrew 2011-2015"

The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Observation:

The command does not specificly move the specified file in the `%F` loop, but `2013 ??? ???`, which means that many more files will be moved as well.

Comment: Try `CHCP 65001` before run your batch file

Comment: Try `move "%~sF"` to use the shortname. Also, you've posted `%F` which is correct for execution directly from the prompt. If you are executing a batch file as claimed, the `%` for the metavariable needs to be doubled.

Comment: Oooh - belay that! Working on a potential  problem that I may post as an "answer" for discussion...

Comment: for a one liner you could try: cmd /u /c (chcp 65001 ^&   <your code>  )

Answer (score 0):

This is my first attempt at a solution, expecting that the `~s` should report the shortname for the file.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
dir /x /a-d "*.mp3"

FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN ('dir /b /a-d "*.mp3" ') DO (
 ECHO "%%~sb" short FOR "%%b"
)
```

It *seemed* to work, until I looked closely:

[image: run report]

Note that the second filename is reported as the shortname for the second *unicode* filename.

So, I stashed that away as a trap, no doubt of interest to @jeb (could be well-known, but I've not tripped over it before)

and then I tried this, which seems to work:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
 
FOR /f "tokens=4delims= " %%b IN ('dir /x /a-d /-c "*.mp3"*^|findstr /v /b /c:" " ') DO (
 ECHO "%%~sb" short FOR "%%b"
)
```

Here, the `dir` list is created with the `/x` option to show the shortname. `/-c` removes thousands separators from the filesize and `/a-d` suppresses directorynames. The output of `dir` is piped (the pipe is escaped, as required) to `findstr` which looks for lines `/v` not-including `/b` at the beginning of the line `/c:" "` a space, which excludes the superfluous report lines.

The resultant lines will have in the 4<sup>th</sup> token either the shortname in the case of non-8.3 filenames, or the 8.3 filename. I use `HH:MM` for time, obviously, so those who use <kbd>Space</kbd>am/pm (as distinct from `am/pm` with no space) will need to choose the 5<sup>th</sup> token.